# Passenger side wheel sits closer to the front of the car than drivers

Tags: ford, suspension, fusion

I have a 2011 Ford Fusion. My passenger side wheel sits 1 finger away from the shielding in the hub (towards the engine / forward) while the driver's side is backward. Not sure what happened to it. What could be the possible causes? I've had upper control arm replaced but everything else is OEM.

Comment: If you could post a photo it would help explain what you are seeing.

Comment: @mikes caster probably. Unless OPs been in an accident this may be normal.

Comment: If I put three fingers in between the tire and the wheel hub's mudguard on the right-hand side of the tire, it will fit and not hit the mudguard/fender. If I do it on the RF it does not fit meaning the wheel/tire sits closer to the engine by half an inch.

Comment: Personally, I'd guess it's a knuckle. If not a knuckle it would be a lowe control arm. @mikes

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it has been in an accident or severely hit a kerb.

You need to get a full chassis check to find which points are no longer in the correct position.

One way of approaching this at home is to drop plumb lines from each of the recognised points (usually from info in the workshop manual) and marking them on the garage floor. As you connect all the points you will, or should, find which points are not correctly located with the others.

If you don't have the info then you could start with any identifiable points such as all the front suspension location points, the hub carriers, the rear suspension points, any points on the chassis that are on both sides pressing points, holes etc

Answer (score 1):

I took it to a shop. They shifted the subframe but the biggest difference was made when the discovered the steering gear was shifted to one side because someone before them had taken the steering wheel off and adjusted it. It's now in perfect alignment.